# Ajax BeginForm POST using MVC and Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-ajax

I keep getting a 404 and searching all over SO and cannot target the issue here. The form is the result of a render action and appears on the home page (home controller). However, I want it to post a different controller action and it keeps giving me a 404. I have included all the correct script for unobtrusive javascript as well as the necessary web.config settings and I'm unable to come across a similar problem from my research.

This is the partial with the form that is being rendered:

```
@model AFS.Models.SearchLocationModel
<div class="site-search-module">
<div class="site-search-module-inside">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchCare", "LevelOfCare", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "searchDiv" }, new { @class = "search-form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h5>Select a category</h5>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Level, Model.LevelSelectList, new { @class = "form-control input-lg selectpicker" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h5>Enter location</h5>
                <input type="text" id="Location" name="Location" class="form-control input-lg selectpicker" placeholder="City, State OR Zip Code" required />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search</button> </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

The controller action is:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult SearchCare(SearchLocationModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {


            SearchLocationModel geocodeModel = Geocode(new SearchLocationModel() { Level = model.Level, Location = model.Location });
            if (geocodeModel.Status == "OK")
            {
                Session["level"] = model.Level;
                return RedirectToRoute("LevelCity", new { level = model.Level, state = geocodeModel.State, city = geocodeModel.City, latitude = geocodeModel.Latitude, longitude = geocodeModel.Longitude });
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Please enter City, State OR Zip Code.");
                return RedirectToAction("SearchWidget", "Home");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("SearchError");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You using `Ajax.BeginForm()` which makes an ajax call. Ajax calls never redirect so all the redirects in the controller make no sense

Comment: I definitely need it to redirect. But even without that, it never gets to the controller action. Why is that?

Comment: Then do NOT use ajax - use `Html.BeginForm()` - and what is the error telling you? (best guess is either you do not have a `LevelOfCareController`, or its in a separate area, or you have nested forms)

Comment: How do I get it to return an error in the partial view then if something doesn't go correctly in the Html.BeginForm post? That's what I'm trying to accomplish here. If successful, I need it to redirect, but if not, then I need to issue a message to the user about incorrect input (in this case, geocoding didn't work).

Comment: Typically, you add a `ModelStateError` and return the view so the validation error is displayed (although you should be adding validation attributes to you model properties and using client side validation to prevent the form being submitted in the first place)

Comment: Thanks, but it won't just update the partial view. I suppose I could return the entire home page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128610/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-jallen).